# Probability of getting 1 in JavaScript Math.Floor((Math.Random() * 1) + 0)

Tags: javascript, math, random, floor

I got this code pattern from most pages on the front page of google search. My intention is to get either 0 or 1. My data is showing all zeroes. Is it safe to assume that this will never give 1? Right now I adjusted it to as below:

```
if(inclusiveUpperBound == 1 && inclusiveLowerBound == 0) {
    oneAdjust = 1;
}

if(!window.useRandomArray && (window.randomArray.length > 0)) {
    randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * (inclusiveUpperBound+oneAdjust)) + (inclusiveLowerBound+oneAdjust)) - oneAdjust;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: What is the expected result? Random float number between 0 and 1 inclusively? Or just integer number 0 or 1? It is unclear now.

Comment: Do you want to get zero or one with equal probability? Then multiply by 2 (wihout adjusting the factor you are adding).

Comment: The answer to the title of your question is 0%. A `1` will never be generated by `Math.random()`.

Comment: _"My intention is to get either 0 or 1"_ What is expected result after 100 calls?

Comment: @4castle Yeah, I think I agree with you. If you put this comment as an answer, I'll accept it though.

Answer (score 4):

> My intention is to get either 0 or 1

You can just use `Math.random()` this way:

```
var eitherOneOrZero = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1;
```

Since [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) returns number in range [0; 1), it is expected to provide the same probability for 0 and 1.

Comment: The JS reference says Math.random outputs a float between 0 inclusive and 1 exclusive. I love your code though.  Much better than mine.

Comment: @Sryn, I ran this solution in a loop one million times and it evaluated to `0` 49.9637% of the time. It doesn't matter that the upper bound is exclusive, because the probability of getting any specific value is so incredibly small.

Comment: @Poosh I'm assuming Yeldar's solution, right? If so, I agree.

Comment: @Sryn, yes, I was running Yeldar's solution. If your intention is to get 0 or 1 with equal likelihood, then I think it is a good solution.

Comment: @Poosh My question didn't explain my 'problem' properly. I just wanted a versatile code that chooses an integer inclusive of the lower and upper bound.  It is just that, that code example will fail at lower bound of 0 and upper bound of 1.  Hence my question to ask about this in a roundabout way whether this community is aware of the Google front page offered code example failing at those bounds.